# How to edit Azure App Service using Azure Python SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I'm following the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-web-app?tabs=cmd#4-write-code-to-provision-and-deploy-a-web-app trying to update an existing App Service using the Python SDK.

Here is my code

```
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
import os

def insert_access_restriction():
    rg_name = os.environ.get('RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME', None)
    location = os.environ.get('LOCATION', None)
    sp_name = os.environ.get('SERVICE_PLAN_NAME', None)
    web_app_name = os.environ.get('WEB_APP_NAME', None)
    sub_id = os.environ.get('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID', None)
    
    app_service_client = get_client_from_cli_profile(WebSiteManagementClient)
    poller = app_service_client.app_service_plans.create_or_update(rg_name,
        sp_name,
        {
            "location": location,
            "reserved": True,
            "sku" : {"name" : "S1"}
        }
    )
    plan_result = poller.result()
    
    poller = app_service_client.web_apps.create_or_update(rg_name,
        web_app_name,
        {
            "location": location,
            "server_farm_id": plan_result.id,
            "site_config": {
                "ip_restriction": {
                    "ip_address": "3.3.3.3/32"
                },
                "ip_restriction": {
                    "ip_address": "4.4.4.4/32"
                }                    
            }
        }
    )
```

The call to this function `app_service_client.app_service_plans.create_or_update` returns

> azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.models._models_py3.DefaultErrorResponseException:
> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'

My location is `centralus`. The goal of this program is to update the ip restrictions on an existing app service programmatically from a Function App when a new list of ip addresses is added to a storage container. The error is very vague, how do I get an existing app service plan, its app service, and then update the app service using the Python SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to update the ip restrictions settings on an existing app service with python sdk, please refer to the following code

1. Create a service principal and assign `Contributor` to the sp

```
az login
# create sp and assign Contributor role to the sp at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"
```

2. Code

```
client_id = 'your sp appId'
secret = 'your sp password'
tenant = 'your sp tenant'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = client_id,
        secret = secret,
        tenant = tenant
)

Subscription_Id = ''

web_client=WebSiteManagementClient(
    credentials,
    Subscription_Id
)
resorurce_group_name='your appservice group name'
name='you appservice name'

web_client.web_apps.create_or_update_configuration(resorurce_group_name, name,{

    'ip_security_restrictions':[

        {
            'ip_address': "0.0.0.0/0", 
            'action': "Allow", 
            'priority': 30, 
            'name': "test"
        }
    ]
})
```

[image]

for more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python#create-or-update-configuration-resource-group-name--name--site-config--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.models.siteconfigresource?view=azure-python)

---

#Update

If you want to run the script in Azure function, please refer to the following steps.

1. Create Azure function
2. Enable Azure MSI for Azure Function
   [image]
3. Assign role fro the MSI
   [image]
   [image]
4. code (I use HTTP trigger to get web app configuration)

```
import logging
import pyodbc
import json
import azure.functions as func
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    creds =MSIAuthentication()
    Subscription_Id = 'e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68'
    group_name='0730BowmanWindowAndLinux2'
    name='413Bowman'

    web_client=WebSiteManagementClient(
        creds,
        Subscription_Id
    )
    result =web_client.web_apps.get_configuration(group_name, name,raw=True)
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result.response.json()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jim, does the "MyApp" name in the service principal need to match the app service name or it can be anything? Also if this were running from a Function App in the same subscription as the App Service is there a way to authenticate using a role so that the code doesn't have to retrieve a password?

Comment: @gary69 "MyApp" name in the service principal can be anything?